# Volume of the region Limit clarification

Tags: integration

Find the volume of the region bounded by $ z=1-y^2, z = 0, x= 2 , x = 4 $

I need clarification in finding the limit.

My work:

$0 \leq z \leq 1-y^2$

$1-y^2 = 0 $

$y = \pm 1 $

$-1 \leq y \leq 1$

$2 \leq x \leq 4$

Are the limits correct? Is the limit of y to be taken from negative to positive (or) from zero  to positive?

That is  $ -1 \leq y \leq 1 $    (or)   $ 0 \leq y \leq 1 $ ? Please advise which is correct.

Comment: Yes your limits are corrects, now you just have to compute the integral to get the volume.

Comment: @Falcon, Thanks a million for confirming.

Comment: Note that the values of $z,y$ are totally independent of $x$.  Therefore, to a large extent, this problem smells like **red herring**.  It is really a problem of calculating area, and then multiplying the area by the width of $\{(x=4) - (x=2)\}.$  By analogy, consider the volume of a cylinder : $(\pi r^2 h).$  With the cylinder, the cross sectional area is also independent of the height *location*.